# How can I loop through all the elements in a two pair STL set<pair<t1,t2>,pair<t1,t2>>?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, auto

Here is the data type I am using.

```
  set< std::pair<string,string>,std::pair<string,string>> foo;
```

Here is my failed attempt at looping over it

```
for(auto &e: foo){
    cout << e.first << " " << e.second // this is where I am having an issue.
}
```

Is it possible to use auto this way? 
e.g

```
e.first, e.second // some c++ magic (i realize -> is wrong)  In pseudo -> //  e.third ...
```

I would love to use auto, but if not how would I write an iterator for the data type I am using?

Comment: But you *are* already looping though the set. The problem is that in your loop `e.first` is the key ***pair*** and `e.second` is the data ***pair***.

Comment: Since when does a `std::set` have key and value? Did you mean `map` instead of `set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something utterly weird.

The signature of set is:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

So you are using `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` as comparator. It will fail to compile as soon as you try to insert something.

But I am pretty sure that's not what you want.

You probably either want

```
map<pair<string, string>, pair<string, string>>;
```

or

```
set<pair<pair<string, string>, pair<string<string>>>;
```

or maybe

```
set<tuple<string, string, string, string>>;
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up needing. `set<pair<pair<string, string>, pair<string, string>>> foo` and then I can access the elements using `                    cout << item1.first << " " << item1.second << "->" << item2.first << " " << item2.second << endl; `